# Returning struct from function defined in thread

Tags: c, function, struct, pthreads, circular-buffer

I have a struct defined like

```
typedef struct{
    int op;
    int id;
    int val;
} command_t;

command_t cmd_buffer[10];
```

I am creating a bunch of threads to work with a struct array in a circular buffer.
In the thread creaction I call the function `start_thread` which calls `removefrombuffer` which is supposed to return a struct or at least pass a struct to the start_thread function

```
void *start_thread (void *arg){
    int i;
    command_t item;
    getfrombuffer(item);
    ///// bunch of operations from the item removed from buffer
}

command_t getfrombuffer (command_t item){
    sem_wait(&fullpositions);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    item = cmd_buffer[buff_read_idx++];
    if(buff_read_idx >= 6)
        buff_read_idx=0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    sem_post(&freepositions);
    return item;    
}
```

Unfortunately after the `start_thread` function calls `getfrombuffer()`, after I try to do operations from that that returned item or simply printf of item.id for example it will return a random valor in memory and not the value that was removed from the buffer.

How can I properly return a structure from a function like this?

Comment: You should study something about pointers, or correct the code as `item = getfrombuffer(item);` in the calling side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that item is passed by value to your function.

You can correct it in two ways:

1. Using a simple return value

---

```
void *start_thread (void *arg){
    int i;
    command_t item = getfrombuffer();
    ///// bunch of operations from the item removed from buffer
}

command_t getfrombuffer (void)
{
    sem_wait(&fullpositions);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    command_t item = cmd_buffer[buff_read_idx++];
    if(buff_read_idx >= 6)
        buff_read_idx=0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    sem_post(&freepositions);
    return item;    
}
```

2. Using pointers

---

```
void *start_thread (void *arg)
{
    int i;
    command_t item;
    getfrombuffer(&item);
    ///// bunch of operations from the item removed from buffer
}

void getfrombuffer (command_t *item)
{
    sem_wait(&fullpositions);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    *item = cmd_buffer[buff_read_idx++];
    if(buff_read_idx >= 6)
        buff_read_idx=0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    sem_post(&freepositions);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never set `item` in the `*start_thread` function to anything. Change `getfromebuffer(item)` to `item = getfrombuffer(item)`.

Another fix would be to change `getfrombuffer` to void type and pass `item` by reference (read: pass a pointer to `item`), making your code as such:

```
void *start_thread (void *arg){
    int i;
    command_t item;
    getfrombuffer(&item);
    ///// bunch of operations from the item removed from buffer
}

void getfrombuffer (command_t* item){
    sem_wait(&fullpositions);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    *item = cmd_buffer[buff_read_idx++];
    if(buff_read_idx >= 6)
        buff_read_idx=0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    sem_post(&freepositions);    
}
```